# How to redirect someone to a page directly after they select an option in a dropdown menu

Tags: html

Basically I have a form and I would like for someone to be redirected to a certain page with each option. After clicking an option I want to redirect them to that page.

My code:

```
<select>
    <option label="Pick your number" value="Number" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="1" value="one></option>
    <option label="2" value="two"></option>
    <option label="3" value="three"></option>
</select>
```

For example: after selecting option two they would be redirected to a page two.html

I know I've worded this a bit confusing, so I hope you guys understand what I mean and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get value from drop down onchange redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494153/get-value-from-drop-down-onchange-redirect)

Comment: Do you want to redirect the user on submit or on option click?

Comment: On option click, I have no submit button.

Comment: It's definitely similar and I think it would solve my problem aswell but I just tried to use his code and none of the options are in the list except the default option, either I'm doing something wrong or he might have used extra code.

Comment: Check this out - it could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag